# Testing Extjs Website with Selenium Error

Tags: javascript, extjs, selenium

I'm testing an Extjs application in selenium and I need to run a Script to set the value of the combo box. I've tried `getEval` command with target

`var combo=Ext.getCmp('combobox name'); combo.setValue('4'); combo.fireEvent('select');`

but I've got the following error:
`[error] Threw an exception: Ext is not defined`

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Arvin, did you find the solution for this problem? The solution below still shows that ext is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about jsExecutor?

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("var combo=Ext.getCmp('combobox name');");
    stringBuilder.append("combo.setValue('4');");
    stringBuilder.append("combo.fireEvent('select');");
    js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

if any other exceptions thrown - try debug step by step in IDE you work

also look [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html) in **Executing JavaScript from Your Test** section:

*JavaScript comes very handy in exercising an application which is not directly supported by selenium. The getEval method of selenium API can be used to execute JavaScript from selenium RC.*

```
public static String[] getAllCheckboxIds () {
             String script = "var inputId  = new Array();";// Create array in java script.
             script += "var cnt = 0;"; // Counter for check box ids.
             script += "var inputFields  = new Array();"; // Create array in java script.
             script += "inputFields = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');"; // Collect input elements.
             script += "for(var i=0; i<inputFields.length; i++) {"; // Loop through the collected elements.
             script += "if(inputFields[i].id !=null " +
             "&& inputFields[i].id !='undefined' " +
             "&& inputFields[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {"; // If input field is of type check box and input id is not null.
             script += "inputId[cnt]=inputFields[i].id ;" + // Save check box id to inputId array.
             "cnt++;" + // increment the counter.
             "}" + // end of if.
             "}"; // end of for.
             script += "inputId.toString();" ;// Convert array in to string.
             String[] checkboxIds = selenium.getEval(script).split(","); // Split the string.
             return checkboxIds;
 }
```

or another example:

```
selenium.getEval("window.document.images.length;");
```

Hope this helps you